# Django access form errors excluding non_field_errors in template

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates

In a django template I'd like to show all form errors on top of the form,
the easiest way is by doing so:

```
{{ form.errors }}
```

The problem is that this also shows the `form.non_field_errors`, these are the entries contained in `form.errors['__all__']`.

I want to show these special errors separately, so I've tried to loop over the dict and check if the key existed:

```
{% for err in form.errors %}
  {% if not err.__all__ %}
    {# print error #}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but apparently this is not possible because in the template we cannot access dictionary keys starting with underscore ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups)).

**Question**: is there a built-in way to access (and possibly print) the standard field errors and separately the non_field_errors?

**Solution** 
This was built on top of Daniel Roseman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48439670/1191416):

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <div class="ui error icon message">
        <ul>
            {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                    <li>{{ error|escape }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            {% for field in form %}
                {% if field.errors %}
                    <li> {{ field.name }}
                        <ul>
                            {% for error in field.errors %}
                                <li>{{ error|escape }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over the fields and access their errors:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% field.errors %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It should be `{{ field.errors }}` instead of `{% field.errors %}` . :)